# sicklms failed to initialized:failed to detect baud rate!

Tags: ros, sicklms, sicktoolbox-wrapper

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
*** Attempting to initialize the Sick LMS...
Attempting to open device @ /dev/ttyMXUSB0
    Device opened!
Attempting to start buffer monitor...
    Buffer monitor started!
Attempting to set requested baud rate...
A Timeout Occurred!  2 tries remaining
A Timeout Occurred!  1 tries remaining
A Timeout Occurred - SickLIDAR::_sendMessageAndGetReply: Attempted max number of tries w/o success!
Failed to set requested baud rate...
Attempting to detect LMS baud rate...
    Checking 19200bps...
A Timeout Occurred!  2 tries remaining
A Timeout Occurred!  1 tries remaining
A Timeout Occurred - SickLIDAR::_sendMessageAndGetReply: Attempted max number of tries w/o success!
    Checking 38400bps...
A Timeout Occurred!  2 tries remaining
A Timeout Occurred!  1 tries remaining
A Timeout Occurred - SickLIDAR::_sendMessageAndGetReply: Attempted max number of tries w/o success!
    Checking 500Kbps...
A Timeout Occurred!  2 tries remaining
A Timeout Occurred!  1 tries remaining
A Timeout Occurred - SickLIDAR::_sendMessageAndGetReply: Attempted max number of tries w/o success!
ERROR: I/O exception - SickLMS::Initialize: failed to detect baud rate!
[ERROR] [1321844482.225130027]: Initialize failed! are you using the correct device path?
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12018/sicklms-failed-to-initialized:failed-to-detect-baud-rate!/) by [sven_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/1417/sven_007/) on ROS Answers with karma: 49 on 2011-11-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It worked after I set the interface of "/dev/ttyMXUSB0" to RS-422.

Thank goodness!

---

Originally posted by [sven_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/1417/sven_007/) with karma: 49 on 2011-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0